# Azure Network Adapter without Windows Admin Center

Tags: azure-networking, windows-admin-center

I want to use Azure Network Adapter, but I don't want to use Windows Admin Center.  Windows Admin Center is a security headache and I don't want it.  I just want to install an Azure Network Adapter on my Windows Server 2022 box.  How can I do this?

For example, can this be done via PowerShell?  Why did Microsoft make this so complex?